# AngularJS - declare ng-model directly on the <form> element

Tags: forms, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

In AngularJS, is there any way to declare ng-model directly on the `<form>` element instead of having to do it on every single control/input of that form and then be able to access the values of the controls in the controller through their names?

Specifically, if you have a form like this,

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="text" name="age">
</form>
```

typically, you'd do something like this,

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.email">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.age">
<form>
```

which then gives you access to the user object and its properties in the controller:

```
$scope.user
$scope.user.email
$scope.user.age
```

I would like to do something like this instead:

```
<form ng-model="user">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="text" name="age">
</form>
```

and then be able to access the values in the controller:

```
$scope.user.email
$scope.user.age
```

The reason I'm asking is that I'm angularizing an existing web project and some of the forms have easily 20 or 30 controls and defining the ng-model individually seems like an overkill.

All the form examples that I'm able to find declare the ng-model on the individual controls. I was also able to dig up this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1716) which basically says that something like this would require a major AngularJS overhaul, so I suspect it may not be possible. But the ticket is from a year ago and perhaps things have changed since then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of the box; no. But you can quite easily write your own directive that does the trick.

```
app.directive('lazyFormModel', function() {
  return {
    require: ['form'],

    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      var modelName = tAttrs.lazyFormModel;

      angular.forEach(tElement.find('input'), function(e) {
        var $e = angular.element(e);
        var name = $e.attr('name');
        $e.attr('ng-model', modelName + '.' + name);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The above will create a directive that will loop through all the containing **input** elements and stamp an **ng-model** attribute on them based on the **name** value. Attach this to a form element and you're good to go:

```
<form lazy-form-model="user">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="text" name="age">
</form>
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/O7ais3?p=preview

**Edit**

As a side note; you can extend this to fit other manipulations too: like custom validations and/or html layout.

**Edit**

> Would you know how I could extend this to work with multiple checkboxes of the same name but different values (a checklist type of input)?

Something like this should handle checkboxes:

```
angular.forEach(tElement.find('input'), function(e) {
  var $e = angular.element(e);
  var name = $e.attr('name');

  var modelProperty = modelName + '.' + name;

  if($e.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
    modelProperty += '.' + $e.attr('value');
  }

  $e.attr('ng-model', modelProperty);
});
```

Updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O7ais3?p=preview).

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm choosing this as the answer as the angular-form-model from jackypan1989's answer works very similarly. Would you know how I could extend this to work with multiple checkboxes of the same name but different values (a checklist type of input)?

Comment: Updated the answer to handle checkboxes

Comment: is there a way to do this with dynamic inputs via `ng-repeat`s?

Comment: @ryeballar It is possible, but you'll need something that will fire after the `ng-repeat` has fired, which AFAIK requires some setup. Take a look at this if you want [dynamic forms without any hassle](https://github.com/McNull/angular-febworms).

Answer (score 2):

There is a custom directive called [angular-form-model](https://github.com/jorgenfb/angular-form-model) which overcomes this problem. It makes every model inside the form automatically bind to the ng-model of form.

For example:

```
<form jfb-form-model="user">
    <input name="email" />
    <input name="age" />
</form>
```

will transfer to

```
<form jfb-form-model="user">
    <input name="email" ng-model="user.email"/>
    <input name="age" ng-model="user.age/>
</form>
```