# how to use angular.js with strongly typed view in asp.net-MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am working on a web application in ASP.NET-MVC. The task is to generate a check box list from database and put some condition on it. There are total 8 items are present in checkbox list and condition is like if second checkbox is checked then the first checkbock is checked automatically and third and fourth check box go disable. and on the selection of them the selected checkboxs values should be added automatically as total cost.  I had achieved the same from using J-Query and javascript.

But one of my friend says that instead of using jquery i should go with the Angular.js this it is much lightweight and easy to use as compare to j-query.

Now i searched for angular and came to know that it is much powerfull and easy to use with html. but when i use it in MVC where the vales are coming from database i am not getting any way to use angular with my code. my code is like

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="@item.serviceName" id="@item.serviceName" value="@item.cost">@item.serviceName
</div>

<div id="price-list" class="col-md-4">

    <label>@item.cost</label>

</div>
}
```

This is generating the checkboxes. now how should i use Angular.js with it 
or it is not possible to achieve the same with angular. or i have to stick with J-Query for that.
Or their is any other java script framework that should i use to achieve the same.

Need your help in this.
Thanks

Comment: Serialize your Model as JSON and load it to JavaScript in an AJAX call, then use Angular and avoid the Razor code. I suggest going through this tutorial first: http://angular.codeschool.com/

Comment: Mixing strongly typed MVC views with Angular doesn't give you much and can confuse you if you're not very good with both technologies.

Comment: @Jasen So you suggest that i have to stick with the jquery.
well is this possible to achieve the same with angular

Comment: @dave thank dave
i think i have to go for the very first step of angular

Comment: If you have an existing site I would find it easier to use jQuery than to restructure it for Angular.

Comment: @Jasen this is link of test server. [test server] http://gocarwash.hukumnama.net/ i have just started it so i have option to move to angular.

Comment: If you have interest in Angular I have found these series of blogs helpful with MVC: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par. Generally, you would avoid strongly typed views.

Comment: What is the problem with adding the needed attributes? This can be done server side (razor) or client side with some directive magic. It's probably easiest to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668815/angularjs-declare-ng-model-directly-on-the-form-element/23669338#23669338).

Comment: @null but the problem is that the fields are generating dynamic and also need to do some condition on each check. have a look here http://gocarwash.hukumnama.net/.  i had done this with jquery
after selecting the service on home page when we move to second page we need to check some conditon

Comment: @RP see this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdbVjpFQe1thsuDZxsSP?p=preview). Plunker doesn't have a ASP.NET MVC backend, but that doesn't matter. Key is the `ng-model` attribute, which will contain a list of boolean values indicating the checked status.